# what is differece between Decision task and business task in BPMN?How implement decision task using alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I am new in alfresco. please tell me,what is differece between Decision task and business task in BPMN?How implement decision task in process using alfresco?
        I am currently using alfresco community version.

Answer (score 0):

**Decision Task**

You use a decision task to select a decision table while designing your process model. A decision table enables you to define a set of business rules that will be applied when it’s executed.

**Business rule task**

A Business rule task executes one or more rules. It is mainly there for compatibility with Alfresco Process Services community.

Comment: thanx,                                                                                          i tried many time to apply decision table in process,but i am not done.so please help me.Also i reffered this link [https://community.alfresco.com/community/bpm/blog/2017/08/23/dmn-decision-tables-101]

Answer (score 0):

In BPMN there is no such thing as "Business" task.
Perhaps you are asking about the difference between a Decision task and a "Business Rule" task.
A decision task is a simple decision based on variables known within the process (process variables).
A "Business Rule" task uses an external rules engine (in the case of Activiti it is Drools) to run a rules service. On completion of the service you will need a "decision" task to orchestrate the folw based on the results of the "Business Rule" task.

In more recent versions of Activiti (both Community and Enterprise editions) there is also a Rules Table task which uses an interpretation of the DMN standard to process a decision.